# Windows Phone Mango - Memory constraint (6 MB) issue

Tags: scheduled-tasks, memory-management, windows-phone-7

As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), background task cannot use more than 6 MB of memory. I ran background task without any code as follows:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Available Memory: " + (DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit - DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage).ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine("Peak Memory: " + DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage.ToString());
    NotifyComplete();
}
```

The code does not contain any logic. Just writing to output window about available memory.

Following is the output of the above:

Available Memory: 1863680
Peak Memory: 4435968

What I am wondering is, without writing any code or allocating memory to object, how is my 4435968 bytes of memory is used? **If 4435968 bytes are used without writing code, what will I be able to do with remaining 1863680 bytes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider that the background agent is a single piece of code, that's 100% separated from the rest of your application.

So when you're not testing it in a debug mode, where the application is actually running, it won't be using ~4mb of memory.

You clearly worry to much. If you're even remotely near of hitting the memory limit for a PeriodicAgent, then I strongly doubt you're doing something that's suitable for a background task.

Comment: I will try to install it on phone and see the memory consumption without debugging. Will let you know the result.

Comment: Don't tell me you tested memory consumption in the emulator.